# Wpf element host flickering issue

Tags: wpf-controls

I have an element host with one WPF control (with only a texblock in it for ex) on  winform. When my application loads, the hosted control  is taking few seconds and it shows a white background for few secs and after only it gets loaded t.  Is there any way to avoid this..
Any ideas are appreciated.

I'm using Microsoft visual studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using a WPF hosting control inside Windows Forms?  My guess is that the WPF stack is initializing and that's what's taking a lot of time.

My suggestions would be twofold:

- I understand that they did some improvements to the WPF stack's loading time in .NET 4.0.  Try upgrading your project to .NET 4.0 and see if this improves.
- When your application starts up initially, try putting in a hidden area in your startup screen which would cause the WPF stack to initialize, so this performance penalty is paid at start time and not at a jarring time during the normal running of your application.